# mysql_query prefixing special characters with accented characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have an odd problem. I'm running MySQL 5.1 on Windows (but production server is Debian Linux  and same issue occurs).

I'm using mysql_query() to UPDATE a table. The description field can occasionally have special characters like degree symbol, plus/minus, etc.

I have looked at the query before being sent to mysql_query() and it looks fine. I run the exact query through mysql client and it works fine. but passing the query to mysql_query() causes of of the special characters to be prefixed with an accented A:

BAKE AT 365 - 383 Â°F FOR 3 HOURS.

Not sure what the heck is going on here, any ideas? I've googled and tried setting everything to UTF-8 and more - whatever I could find.

I'm out of options, converting to html entities is not a option because this text is converted to PDF and various output in other technologies like Access 97 that don't render the entity properly - so the print out has `&deg;` which confuses the guys reading the documents.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The degree symbol in UTF-8 happens to correspond to the characters Â° in the Latin-1 encoding. You are not setting your database connection encoding correctly, so the database is misinterpreting the characters you are sending it. Set [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset) to `'utf8'` after connecting to the database.

See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for more in-depth info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I diddn't work though :( I am missing something. I will have to read over that article you posted to better understand I guess. Everything I could possibly set to utf-8 I have and still no luck.